# JavaScript repeat action when mouse held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there to have a JavaScript function repeated every so many milliseconds that an html button is held down?  It would be great if this could be done with standard JavaScript, but using jQuery or a jQuery plugin would be great too.

Answer (score 32):

On the [`mousedown()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousedown) event, this code starts a repeating timer (every 500ms in this example) that is cancelled as soon as the [`mouseup()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseup) event occurs. This should be adaptable to what you want:

```
var intervalId;
$("#button").mousedown(function() {
  intervalId = setInterval(do_something, 500);
}).mouseup(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});

function do_something() {
  // whatever
}
```

See [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Example) for more information on clearing timers.

Comment: If you want the event to occur right away, AND every 500 milliseconds, just call `do_something()` immediately before calling setInterval.

Comment: @TylerCollier Thanks for pointing out. Then it works like the click event plus the repeated action. Very handy. In my case I also had to pass parameters, for this you have to do assign an anonymous function: `setInterval( function() { myfunction(valueA, valueB); }, 500 );`

Comment: @TylerCollier can someone tell me why wont this stop? http://jsfiddle.net/oxpku7f1/1/

Comment: @Arbaaz, it's the `alert()` call that causes this, because the normal flow (with the alert popping up) is disrupted. Change the alert to e.g. `console.log('a')` and it will stop when you mouseup.

Answer (score 7):

I would use the javascript function `setInterval()` within a function that gets called on mouse down.

```
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="inter=setInterval(startAction, 1*1000);"
onmouseup="clearInterval(inter);" value="click here" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function startAction(){
        //whatever you want done
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var intervalId;
$("#button").mousedown(function() {
  intervalId = setInterval(do_something, 500);
}).mouseup(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}).mouseleave(function() {
//this should help solve the problem that occurs when the mouse leaves the button while pressed down
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});

function do_something() {
  // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I see a problem with both solutions listed above.

`onmouseup` is only triggered if the mouse is released while it is over the button. If the user keeps the mouse down then moves the mouse away before releasing it then `clearInterval` is never fired and so `do_something` will fire forever.

You would need to add another event, "`onmouseout`", that also calls `clearInterval`.

Comment: True but please make this a full answer by adding sample code.