# onmousedown to call a function over and over like onkeydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to make it so onmousedown is repeatedly called if the left mouse button mouse is held down. Right now it only fires once when it is clicked.

```
    wHandle.onmousedown = function (event) {
        console.log('mouse button is being held down!'); // does not work
    };
```

This is how I'd like it to function (this works with space, it calls the function over and over as long as space is being held down):

```
    wHandle.onkeydown = function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 32: // space
                console.log('space is being held down!'); // works!
            break;
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript repeat action when mouse held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934986/javascript-repeat-action-when-mouse-held-down)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the addEventListener and calling the a function in the second parameter.

```
wHandle.addEventListener("mousedown", exampleFunction)
```

Also, haven't tested this so not 100% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet for getting the expected result

```
var interval;
window.onmousedown = function() {
    interval = setInterval(handleMouseDown, 1); 
};
window.onmouseup =function() {
    clearInterval(interval); 
};
function handleMouseDown() {
   console.log('mouse down');
}
```

Hope this helps!!!